# Android - Bug with EditText with digits parameter

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am currently experiencing a strange bug with EditText with the `android:digits` parameter.
Here is the XML of the EditText :

```
<EditText
  android:id="@+id/edittext"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:gravity="center_vertical"
  android:hint="@string/some_text"
  android:imeOptions="actionDone"
  android:singleLine="true"
  android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\\ "
  android:maxLength="140"
  android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_small"/>
```

As you can see, this EditText allows the user to type only alpha-numerics characters.

Now, if I try to use this EditText, the EditText is correctly filtering the chars i'm typing 
but ... if I type some chars then directly followed by `%`, the previously typed chars are copied in the EditText !

Eg: I'm typing on my keyboard `hello%%`, the result in the EditText will be `hellohellohello`.

Has any of you already experienced such a bug ? Is it from the Android platform ? Should I report it or has it already been ?

For information, my device is a Nexus 4 with Android 4.3.

Thank you !

Answer (score 5):

The problem is with the Android Keyboard (AOSP). I was trying it using SwiftKey and couldn't recreate it. I changed to the default keyboard and the problem occurs.

The problem occurs because Android Keyboard is trying to learn/suggest words you're typing in. I'm not sure if the bug has been reported, but you can avoid this problem by using `android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"`

Comment: Thx for your tests. I tried with the standard Android Keyboard, i don't have an external keyboard on my phone. Unfortunately, i can't really disable the text suggestions for my EditText.